# Given a matrix $A$, find a matrix $S$ such that $S^{-1}AS$ is of specific form

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking for a matrix $S$ that transforms $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&-1\\-1&1&-1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ into $$S^{-1}AS=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

At first I found the eigenvalues of A to be $1,\pm i$ so my guess is that maybe I can use somewhat of a real jordan decomposition to get it? Not sure though how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complex eigenvalue pair indicates that $A$ performs a (possibly scaled) rotation in some plane. This plane is spanned by the corresponding complex eigenvectors $(i,i,1)^T$ and $(-i,-i,1)^T$. (The eigenvectors will, like the eigenvalues, come in complex conjugate pairs.) By taking real and imaginary parts of these eigenvectors you can find real vectors that span the same plane. You might need to fiddle with their signs to get the rotation to be in the desired direction.

By inspection, an eigenvector of $1$ is $(0,1,0)^T$, so let $$S=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&1 \\ 1&0&1 \\ 0&1&0 \end{bmatrix}.$$ Then $$S^{-1}AS = \begin{bmatrix}-1&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0&0&-1\\-1&1&-1\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ as required.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!